# Java unable to open main class and jar file

Tags: java, maven, command-line, jar

I've written a Java chat application using client/server architecture. As a build tool I've used Maven. The server side interface is based on command-line and the problem is that I can't run the application by cmd neither with command

```
java Main
```

from {basedir}/target/classes (Main is my main class), nor with command opening the jar file

```
java -jar ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

form {basedir}/target. I haven't created any packages for my classes, they are placed in {basedir}/src/main/java directory. When I try load my Main class, this is the output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

When I try to open my jar file, this is the output:

```
Unable to access jarfile ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The whole project runs really well when I run it in IntelliJ. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** 

I've moved my classes to pl.dsdev.server package, when I run

```
java -jar ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

this is the output:

```
no main manifest attribute, in ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pl.dsdev.projects</groupId>
<artifactId>ChatServer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>pl.dsdev.server.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be java -jar ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml

Comment: I think you need java -jar ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main

Comment: also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785015/create-jar-file-from-multiple-project-dependent-to-each-other/43785828#43785828) to see the best way to create an executable jar with maven.

Comment: @EssexBoy no. The whole point of the -jar option is to execute the main class specified in the manifest of the jar file.

Comment: @JBNizet ok sorry, my ESP was failing me there :)

Comment: Check your MANIFEST.MF file inside the jar in META-INF it has to contain a line with the following syntax Main-Class: classpath.MainClass

Comment: I edited my post, moved classes to the package pl.dsdev.server and tried to run app from cmd like this: java -jar ChatServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Okey, it is working now. I don't know what was the reason, but after I did mvn clean package and tried to run it again it finally worked. Thanks for you time :)

Comment: please mark as solved

Comment: I will, just need to wait 2 days to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, it is working now. I don't know what was the reason, but after I did

```
mvn clean package
```

and tried to run it again it finally worked.